# S3 bucket: Uploaded file size showing as 0 bytes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, data-migration

I have an AWS S3 bucket configured with sftp. I am using WinScp to copy data from server to S3 bucket. So I am uploading a 600 Gb file using WinScp. But after the upload is complete the file size on S3 is showing only 0 bytes. I did not get any error messages while copying. Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "AWS S3 bucket configured with sftp"? Are you referring to [AWS Transfer for SFTP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/what-is-aws-transfer-for-sftp.html)? Does it work for smaller files? Instead of using SFTP, have you considered using Amazon S3 directly (eg using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/))?

Comment: Yes John, I mean AWS transfer for SFTP. It is working for smaller files. One of the files that was successfully copied was 50 GB. Our op-prem system is not associated with S3. So, I cannot use aws CLI.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using Golang, commenting the following line resolved my issue.

```golang
    // Open the file from the file path
    upFile, err := os.Open(imageFile)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("could not open local filepath [%v]: %+v", imageFile, err)
    }
    defer upFile.Close()

    // Get the file info
    // upFileInfo, _ := upFile.Stat()
    // var fileSize int64 = upFileInfo.Size()
    // fileBuffer := make([]byte, fileSize)
    // upFile.Read(fileBuffer) // -->> This line was the issue.
```

Hopefully this will resolve your issue too.