# Image uploaded to s3 bucket from android gives size 0 bytes

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, kotlin, amazon-s3

I'm successfully connected to s3 bucket, Image is uploading to s3 bucket but in s3 bucket it shows image size 0 byte,
Image URL is also not showing any result in Browser, Please help me 
I'm using Below code to upload image to s3 bucket , Please help me out

```
 fun uploadtos3(context:Context, file:File) {
        if (file != null)
        {
            val credentialsProvider = CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                    context,
                    poolId, // Identity Pool ID
                    Regions.AP_SOUTH_1 // Region
            )
            val s3 = AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider)
            val transferUtility = TransferUtility(s3, context)
            val observer = transferUtility.upload(
                    buketName, //this is the bucket name on S3
                    file.getName(),
                    file,
                    CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead //to make the file public
            )
            observer.setTransferListener(object:TransferListener {
                override fun onStateChanged(id:Int, state:TransferState) {
                    if (state.equals(TransferState.COMPLETED))
                    {}
                    else if (state.equals(TransferState.FAILED))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to upload", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }
                override fun onProgressChanged(id:Int, bytesCurrent:Long, bytesTotal:Long) {
                    var percentage:Int = ((bytesCurrent / bytesTotal * 100).toInt())
                    Log.e("Status", "Percentage" + percentage)
                }
                override fun onError(id:Int, ex:Exception) {
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why didn't you add some log to this function, I think it can help

override fun onError(id:Int, ex:Exception) {
                }

And also, I noticed that you just set the listener after calling the method upload

Comment: @VõQuangHòa I add log for Error but it never execute,and my state log says COMPLETED.

Comment: For golang users, please check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59335810/s3-bucket-uploaded-file-size-showing-as-0-bytes/71575549#71575549